# Existe forma de editar el contenido en vivo estando convertido a base64

Tags: javascript, base64

Por ejemplo un pdf o algo así, ya sea en vivo o des-codificar y volviendo a codificar con el mismo link de antes ¿es posible?

Comment: Para poderte ayudar, necesitaría entender mejor la intención de lo que deseas realizar, creo que a la pregunta le faltan bastantes detalles.
No obstante, creo intuir que lo que quieres es que un archivo de un servidor http://x/algo.pdf pueda ser modificado directamente en javascript y mostrado con la misma URL, todo eso debe realizarse en backend, por lo que si deseas utilizar JavaScript en front-end no sería posible.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

En realidad esta pregunta tiene sentido!! Si, si se puede desde el cliente modificar un fichero en base64, convirtiendolo a blob, modificandolo mediante una liberia o tu base de conocimientos de ficheros pdf jajaja (mejor la libreria) y posteriormente pasandolo a base64 de nuevo. Pero el contenido de la base64 se modificará  y la URL será diferente.

Para decodificar la base64 debes utilizar esta función te la linkeo ahí:

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/atob

Espero que esto solucione tu problema.

Edición:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-lib

Te paso una libreria de edición de pdf para web deberias incluirla en tu index.html tal que así:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/pdf-lib/dist/pdf-lib.min.js"></script>
```

Un Saludo!

Comment: `PD: No hagas mucho caso ha gente que te diga que no se puede hacer, por que demuestrán su desconocimiento, no el tuyo.` Ese comentario **sobra**. Aquí no estamos para juzgar el conocimiento de nadie.

Comment: No, es mas productivo aumentar la toxicidad de este stackoverflow, acosando a un novato por una pregunta basica sobre posibilidades de los clientes web actuales y luego a mi por consiguiente... Lo que estais consiguiendo es que la gente que da respuestas y no puntos negativos se vuelva al stackoverflow de ingles... Bravo....

Comment: La pregunta, en el estado actual, no cumple con las normas del sitio https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Las respuestas compuestas de solamente enlaces, se consideran de baja calidad (¿Que pasa si el enlace cambia?). No hay mucho mas que decir.

Comment: Buenas, Raul. Nuestro fin último es un sitio con preguntas y respuestas de gran calidad a la par que ayudar a la gente. Se pueden ambas pero no solo ayudar. Si la pregunta es pobre o mal explicada ha de mejorarase para poder responderse. Por eso está cerrada. Si no está cerrada y su calidad no es la suficiente, por favor no respondas si no guia al usuario en los comentarios. Una vez mejorada la pregunta puedes responderle. Un saludo